# Reading in a file by int, then words

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I have a text file that resembles

`1 \t words words words words`
`2 \t words words words words`

where the `# is the line #`, followed by a tab, then followed by random words

I need to read in the int, store it, then skip the \t, and read in each word individually while keeping track of that words position.

I was hoping I could it with `getline(file, word, ' ')`, and a counter but that grabs my first word as `1 \t words`.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a suggestions site, is a QA site. Ask us a specific question and we will help you.

Comment: okay...  Specifically, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Manu343726 I don't really think this deserves a downvote. The guy tried to solve the problem but he is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `stringstream` and `getline`,

```
getline(file, line);
std::stringstream ssline(line);
int num;
ssline >> num;
std::string word;
while(ssline >> word){
// do whatever you want. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't say how many words there are on a line, then the simple answer is to do it in two steps.

1. Read a whole line into a string with getline
2. Place that string into a std::istringstream and read the line number and following words from the std::istringstream

then repeat from step 1